# Proving logic statements

Tags: logic, proof-writing

For x ∈ ℝ, define by:
⌊x⌋ ∈ ℤ ∧ ⌊x⌋ ≤ x ∧ (∀z ∈ ℤ, z ≤ x ⇒ z ≤ ⌊x⌋).

Use this definition to prove or disprove the following with a structured proof technique:
∀x  ∈ ℝ, ∀y  ∈ ℝ, x  > y  ⇒ ⌊x⌋ ≥ ⌊y⌋.

I understand  I need to start with assuming the domain to be true aswell as the antecedent, then equating a value for x as something and continuing it onwards all the way towards the concluding statement, but I'm fairly new to this and could use some help in proving the thinking part of this

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that : $x > y$ and - for contradiction - that : $⌊x⌋ < ⌊y⌋$.

Thus :

> $⌊x⌋ < ⌊y⌋ \le y < x$

where the first inequality holds by assumption above, the second by definition of $⌊y⌋$ and the third again by assumption.

Thus, with $z = ⌊y⌋$, we have $z \in \mathbb Z$ such that $z \le x$; thus, from def of $⌊x⌋$ :

> $⌊y⌋ = z \le ⌊x⌋$

contrary to our assumption that : $⌊x⌋ < ⌊y⌋$.

Answer (score 0):

Many students find learning methods of proof construction very challenging.  Some suggestions follow.

Start with some exploration, write out some relevant deductions, especially those which could lead to the conclusion.  What can be derived using the theorems already given recently or even previously on the same homework assignment?

Similar to writing a paper, start with a rough draft for a paper.  Write what some call a proof plan or outline.  This typically breaks the proof down into subgoals, similar to a two step or multistep word problem.  When the logic is clear, then rewrite more formally.

When developing a proof plan, consider start with the conclusion and work backwards.  Be careful in the final, formal proof, to reverse the direction and do not assume the conclusion.

Be familiar with common proof methods and styles:

- Mathematical induction
- To prove, $A$ is subset of $B$, choose any $x$ in $A$, show $x$ is in $B$.
- Proof by contradiction
- [Two column formatting style](http://grotongeometry.wikispaces.com/Completing+proofs+in+2-column+and+paragraph+form)

Some proofs start with identities, like $x = x$, especially those with no hypotheses.

For algebra proofs, adding special forms of zero, such as $6x - 6x = 0$.
**Prove:** $x^2 +9 = (x+3)^2 -6x$. 
$x^2 + 9 =$
$(x^2 + 9) + (6x - 6x) =$
$(x^2 +6x +9) -6x =$ 
$ (x+3)^2 -6x = (x+3)^2 -6x$

Note how it ends with a reflexive statement of the desired conclusion.

Likewise, it is common to multiply by $f / f$ or unique forms of $1$.
Some courses or professors discourage adding, subtracting, multiplying or dividing to both sides of an equation.